# Error LNK2001 when installing node-java

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, java-native-interface

I'm trying to install node-java https://github.com/joeferner/node-java on

```
Windows 7 64-bit
JDK 6.45 32bit
MS Visual Studio 2013
node.js v6.9.5
```

I getting a LNK2001 error:

```
java.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_JNI_CreateJavaVM      [C:\Users\seven\workspace\silver\deployment
s\apps\electron-quick-start\node_modules\java\build\nodejavabridge_bindings.vcxproj]
C:\Users\seven\workspace\silver\deployments\apps\electron-quick-  start\node_modules\java\build\Release\nodejavabridge_bindings.node : fatal error   LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals     [C:\Users\seven\workspace\silver\deployments\apps\electron-quick-  start\node_modules\java\build\nodejavabridge_bindings.vcxproj]
 gyp ERR! build error
```

What i doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it is using the 32-bit JDK and not picking up a 64-bit JDK.

Comment: Yes, i'm sure (install jdk-6u45-windows-i586.exe)

Comment: @Andrew: Same here. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @SKuijers: No, I didn't find the solution. We declined to use node-java
on the our project. Nothing you will not help.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue by installing the 32-Bit version of Node and when rebuilding passing the [right arch flag](https://github.com/astro/node-expat/issues/59) to node gyp.

`--arch=ia32`

All worked well after this. I could use the node-java lib successfully in an Electron app. Both in dev and in a packaged app. The problem I faced after that was that ASAR compression somehow added `?//` operator which lead me to not being able to use the packaged app on other computers :S.